# Cassandra Dev Center not working

Tags: eclipse, cassandra

I am trying to launch Cassandra's dev center but I get the following error, right after the dev center launch:

```
No editor descriptor for id org.eclipse.ui.internal.emptyEditorTab
```

Here is a screenshot of the problem
[image]

I've updated java on my mac but it's still not working. How can I fix this?

Many thanks

Comment: More details would help. For example, what steps are you taking that result in the error? Can you include a screen shot that shows what you're doing and seeing?

Comment: thanks for the interest, @E-Riz, I updated the question accordingly

Comment: What happens if you close that editor tab; can you use the tool OK?

Comment: No, I cannot write any CQL query. When I open a new tab or load a .cql file, I get an empty unclickable tab

Comment: hi, i used dev center in ubuntu and windows 8, it worked fine , but in some of mac os it's not working correctly, i suggest you install dev center on another linux distribution and check if it's work or not

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to remove all DevCenter settings. On Mac OSX, settings are stored in your profile directory ~/.DevCenter or ~/.devcenter. On restart, DevCenter will recreate them.